# How to show always 5 items in Action mode menu like WhatsApp in Android toolbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionmode

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_reply"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_reply_white_24dp"
        android:title="Reply"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_favourite"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_grade_white_24dp"
        android:title="Favourite"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_info"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_outline_white_24dp"
        android:title="Info"
        android:visible="false"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_delete"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_white_24dp"
        android:title="Delete"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_copy"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_content_copy_white_24dp"
        android:title="Copy"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_right_arrow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_right_bold_white_24dp"
        android:title="Forward"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_message"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_right_bold_white_24dp"
        android:title="Message xyz"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_call"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_right_bold_white_24dp"
        android:title="Call xyz"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

I'm using Action mode menu while long click on list item. It is always showing max 2 items, even it has space to show more items in Action mode menu. I'm assigning `android:showAsAction = "always"` for all the items. I'm expecting to design screen like WhatsApp long press showing 5 items with icons.

[image]

Comment: Can you add your `menu.xml` please

Comment: Add `app:showAsAction="always"` to icons u want to show in ur menu xml file

Comment: It is showing always max two items and over flow menu.I have attached menu.xml.

Comment: Are you using toolbar? If you are not using toolbar, you change to android:showAsAction="always", I think...

Comment: @Guilherme P: I'm using toolbar only. I'm facing this issue action mode menu and option menu both the places. I want to show action menu like whatsapp but it is showing only 2 items and rest are falling in over flow menu even u have space to accommodate all 5 items

Comment: That code seems normal... I would suggest to make some tests.. Like, let only one item always visible... then, two..., then 3... etc... Maybe, toolbar is not handling well the fact that you have too many items and all of them are set to be displayed always

Comment: I've solved this problem before, but vaguely remember how it done. Maybe solved by using `android:orderInCategory`.

Answer (score 2):

Use **android:showAsAction="always"** property along with **app:showAsAction="always"**.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_reply"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_reply_white_24dp"
    android:title="Reply"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:showAsAction="always" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **import android.support.v7.view.ActionMode** and

**yourActionMode = startSupportActionMode(mActionModeCallback)**

it solves this problem.

Comment: The androidx import statement is import androidx.appcompat.view.ActionMode;    Works great!